# Create a URL that opens a web page at specified text

Tags: url, syntax

I'm trying to figure out the correct URL syntax to open a web page at specified text, rather than at the top of the page. For example, on the page http://softwarebychuck.com/febe/, I would like the URL to open the page on the first line that contains the string "Version 8.3.1". What is the correct URL syntax to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Typical syntax would be `http://softwarebychuck.com/febe/#version_8.3.1` where `version_8.3.1` is an *anchor* defined in the page source, i.e. `<a href="#version_8.3.1>...</a>`.  However, the page you reference does not seem to have any such anchors.

Comment: Are you the editor or the viewer?

Comment: Thank you. I'm a user, trying to share the info with other users. So I suppose I am the viewer, in the terms you used.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use HTML anchors. Anchors can be linked to an HTML element ID. If I inspect the HTML around the "Version 8.3.1" string, there is a `blockquote` element with the ID `FEBE8.3.1`.

You can reference it by putting a `#` between the URI path and the ID:

```
http://softwarebychuck.com/febe/#FEBE8.3.1
```

Or in HTML:

```
<a href="http://softwarebychuck.com/febe/#FEBE8.3.1">test</a>
```

(tested on Firefox 48.0)

Comment: Thanks. How did you find the blockquote element, if I may trouble you just a bit further?

Comment: Just look through the HTML source of the page (CTRL+U in FF) or use the inspector in Firefox or Chrome (this tidies up the source a lot). If this answers your question, please mark it with the green check mark left of the post.